How to calculate the derivative of a function of an ODE flow?
Let's consider a differential equation in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = f(\mathbf{x})
$$
with $f$ smooth or even analytic.
Let also $\varphi^t(\mathbf{x})$ be the flow of the differential equation.
Given a non-negative function $h:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$, let's define another function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^+\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$
$$
g(\mathbf{x},t):=h(\mathbf{x}-\varphi^t(\mathbf{x}))
$$
I now am trying to calculate the derivatives of $g$, in particular
$$
\frac{dg}{dt},\qquad\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{\partial g}{\partial\mathbf{x}}
$$
Here's what I tried:
$$
\frac{dg}{dt} = \nabla h\cdot\frac{\partial(\mathbf{x}-\varphi^t(\mathbf{x}))}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \nabla h\cdot\left(\mathbb{I}-\frac{\partial \varphi^t(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)\cdot f(\mathbf{x})
$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity matrix. Now, since
$$
\varphi^t(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} + f(\mathbf{x})t+O(t^2),
$$
then
$$
\frac{\partial\varphi^t(\mathbf{x})}{\partial\mathbf{x}} = \mathbb{I} + Jf(\mathbf{x})t + O(t^2)
$$
where $Jf$ is the Jacobian of $f$, so one can write
$$
\frac{dg}{dt} = \nabla h\cdot\left(\mathbb{I}-(\mathbb{I} + Jf(\mathbf{x})t + O(t^2))\right)\cdot f(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla h\cdot (-Jf(\mathbf{x})t+O(t^2))\cdot f(\mathbf{x})
$$
As for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$, I am unsure how I should consider the variable $t$; I think I should calculate the derivative like so:
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = \nabla h\cdot (-\dot\varphi^t(\mathbf{x})) = -\nabla h\cdot f(\mathbf{x})
$$
Are my calculations correct?

Can you define the flow?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend the flow of a differential equation is a diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ that maps a point $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(0)$ to its future position at time $t$, $\mathbf{x(t)}$.

Thanks, I might come back to this later

In this context, the initial point $\bf x$ is a constant, the $t$ derivative makes no sense.

@LutzLehmann Could you please expand your comment? It makes sense to take the $t$ derivative of the flow...

I mean the total $t$ derivative as it is currently derived and written. Of course, $\phi^t({\bf x})$ depends on $t$, and is the only such term in the expression.

@LutzLehmann my confusion is precisely the reason of asking this question

An attempt to clarify: You mean $\varphi^t(x_0) = x(t)$, where $\dot{x} = f(x)$ and $x(0) = x_0$? You should distinguish between the solution $x$ and the initial value $x_0$. Not doing so has lead to errors in your argument.

Let me show you how I interpret it: In your case, $g(x_0, t)= h(x_0-x(t))$ and $x(0) = x_0$. So, applying the chain rule, $\partial_t g(x_0, t) = \nabla h(x_0-x(t))^\top (-\dot{x}(t)) =- \nabla h(x_0-x(t))^\top f(x)$.

@HyperbolicPDEfriend thank you. Your result is exactly whay I got for $\partial_t g$. What about $\frac{dg}{dt}$ and $\partial_x g$? Could you please expand your comment into an answer?
